# trouble with <div> rendering

Tags: jsp, html

I have trouble with  while rendering. 
my jsp code is something like  :

```
<h1 class="noBtmPadding">
<spring:message code="${pageHeader}"/>
</h1>

<c:if test="${not empty validationBean.message}">
<span id="error">
${validationBean.message}</span>
</c:if>

<tiles:insertAttribute name="questionContent"/>

<div id="buttons" align="right">

<input type="submit" value='<spring:message code="saveAndExit"/>' name="_eventId_saveAndExit"/>

</div>
```

validationbean.message -> optional and would show up only if there is error message on page.

When first page renders it has some input boxes and on submit  -validationbean.message might get populated(if error is there in input) and page re-renders.
Thn coems the problem.
first render is perfect. all divs are correction 
-QuestionContent is a separate JSP file (wrapped by some div)
With validation error, my whole format gets messed up .

Errors shows up in a bordered box and  question content wont go in the next line but start start right after box. 
I tried 
 and everything.
Using  div instead of  but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

So... I guess you need to fix the HTML your validation method is outputting. Make sure all tags are being closed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

${validationBean.message} is plain text message from java method.It doesnt have any formatting.
I  have 'error' style defined in CSS file.
It puts some color -coding and borders  around text.